# How to use the NSPredicate for searching a string inside the array of array's?

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I have a array like this

[
[121,131,122,123,213],[131,112,111],[121,1112,1311],[154,156,178,12],[134,154,121,171]];

I want to get the arrays contains Which 121 string using predicate.
 Please Give suggestions.

Comment: There are only ints in your array, no strings. And why would you want to use nspredicate, just filter the array. what language? swift or objective-c?

Comment: what is the exact desired outcome and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 NSArray *array = @[ @[@"121",@"131",@"122",@"123",@"213"],@[@"131",@"112",@"111"],@[@"121",@"1112",@"1311"],@[@"154",@"156",@"178",@"12"],@[@"134",@"154",@"121",@"171"]];

 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF == %@", @"121"];
 NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
 NSLog(@"%@", filtered);
```

Comment: thank you its working fine. i have a small doubt if the array's are in the dictionaries like this  [
 { Name:@"aj";  statusids:@[@"121",@"125",@"127"]; };
 { Name:@"Vijay";  statusids:@[@"191",@"187",@"405"];  },
 { Name:@"Marko";  statusids:@[@"201",@"121",@"187"]; },
 { Name:@"David";  statusids:@[@"191",@"121",@"405"]; },
 ]; How to use the predicate to get the dictionary having 121 please give Suggestions